# rspec & rails 3 cannot find model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to put some specs around a new rails 3 project I am working on, and my first test doesn't seem to be able to find a model.

I've installed rspec from the command line using:

```
sudo gem install rspec --pre
```

and then I put the following in my Gemfile

```
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.0.beta.1"
```

But when I run my test I get

```
./spec/models/world_spec.rb:1: uninitialized constant World (NameError)
rake aborted!
Command /opt/local/bin/ruby  -Ilib -Ispec "./spec/models/world_spec.rb" failed
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.4/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:71:in 'define'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1112:in 'verbose'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.4/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:57:in 'send'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.0.0.beta.4/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:57:in 'define'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in 'call'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in 'execute'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in 'each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in 'execute'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in 'synchronize'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in 'invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in 'invoke'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in 'invoke_task'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in 'top_level'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in 'each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in 'top_level'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in 'top_level'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in 'run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in 'standard_exception_handling'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in 'run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/opt/local/bin/rake:19:in 'load'
/opt/local/bin/rake:19
```

My spec is in spec/models/world_spec.rb, and looks like

```
    describe World, "#hello" do
      it "should be invalid" do
        World.new.should be_invalid?
      end
    end
```

I tried adding a line like `require "app/model/world"` and `require "world"` but to no success.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems in rails 3 I need to `require 'spec_helper'`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe World do
  it "should be invalid" do
    World.new.should be_invalid?
  end
end
```

But that might just be because I'm running it from `rake spec` if you're using watchr or some other mechanism you might be able to get that done for you.

Comment: what do you have in spec_helper ?